# iterate through a datatable of rows using `Next` and `Previous` buttons

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I would like to iterate through a datatable of rows using `Next` and `Previous` buttons.

My form has the following:

```
[Ticket Ref]
[Short Description]
[Next Step]
[Last Updated]
```

Through the life of a case, you might get multiple updates. Therefore I may have 5 rows in the database relating to a particular `Ticket Reference`. `Comments` and `Last Updated` will obviously be different.

When the form loads it will display the last record in the database into the text boxes i.e the last row from the query. I would then like to click `Previous` and see the previous rows. But if i click on `Next` I expect it to loop through. i.e go to the next record. So if im on record 1, then it needs to go to 2.

I have tried counting the clicks but this isnt very helpful as when the form first loads `count` will be `0` and if i click `Previous` then i will get a `Row out of position -1` error.

**My previous button looks like this:**

```
    protected void btnPrevious_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DAL.TicketsDataSetTableAdapters.TicketDetailsTableAdapter eobj = new DAL.TicketsDataSetTableAdapters.TicketDetailsTableAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = eobj.GetTicketUpdates(txtSupportRef.Text);

        int i = 0;

        if (i < dt.Rows[0].Table.Rows.Count - 1 || i != 0)
        {
            i--;
            txtShortDesc.Text = dt.Rows[0].Table.Rows[i]["ShortDesc"].ToString();
            txtNextStep.Text = dt.Rows[0].Table.Rows[i]["NextStep"].ToString();
            txtLastUpdated.Text = dt.Rows[0].Table.Rows[i]["LastUpdated"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            //no records to see more.
        }
    }
```

**My next button looks like this:**

```
    protected void btnNext_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DAL.TicketsDataSetTableAdapters.TicketDetailsTableAdapter eobj = new DAL.TicketsDataSetTableAdapters.TicketDetailsTableAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = eobj.GetTicketUpdates(txtSupportRef.Text);

        int i = 0;

        if (i < dt.Rows[0].Table.Rows.Count - 1)
        {
            i++;
            txtShortDesc.Text = dt.Rows[0].Table.Rows[i]["ShortDesc"].ToString();
            txtNextStep.Text = dt.Rows[0].Table.Rows[i]["NextStep"].ToString();
            txtLastUpdated.Text = dt.Rows[0].Table.Rows[i]["LastUpdated"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            //no records to see more.
        }
    }
```

Also the user will have the ability to load different ticket references into the form. So i need the ability to quickly iterate based on the loaded ticket.

If you need more info please ask.

Comment: I am using C# ASP.NET framework 4.0

Comment: Use a hidden field to store click count so it posts back with the form. That way it won't reset.

Comment: So what happens when the form loads and the click count is zero but im on record 5 from the database, Clicking previous will then go to `-1` which doesnt exist. I need it to go back to the previous record, i.e record 4. etc...

Comment: What i think i should do is load ALL records based on ticket reference to a data table and then loop through that using the buttons... But i have no clue on how to do that.. Any advise or examples are appreciated.

Comment: If you store click count in a hidden field then it would not be zero on record 5, it would be 5 because form fields survive the round trip in viewstate. Ideally you would use Ajax techniques to pull all records for a ticket and scroll through them with JavaScript.

Comment: Do you have a link that could help me with my question? Should i be searching "how to display all records and loop through via Ajax?"

Comment: Tough question, there are so many ways. But yes try that and maybe also search plunker or jsfiddle with "prvious/next" keywords.

Comment: 1) Can you please upload a screenshot of the form, and 2) How many rows are expected in the table? It may be more efficient for small table to load all the data and page through it with javascript. For large table it may be more efficient to optimize indexes to retrieve a single row or a chunk of rows at a time and load it via AJAX. What you are doing, using postbacks that go back to the server and load the data each time and then return the entire response HTML is not efficient and usually results in poor UX. If you have to, load only one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will work if you properly manage the index wrap-around.

You just need to reset the index to `0` when it hits the end of the data set, and set it to `DataTable.Rows.Count - 1` when it goes back from the beginning.

INITIALIZE

```
 DataTable dt;
 protected override void Page_Load
 {
     // querying each load gets expensive; consider alternative patterns?
     dt = GetData(txtSupportRef.Text);
     if (!IsPostBack)
     {
         int i = 0;
         ViewState["recordIndex"] = i;
         PopulateForm(i);
     }
 }
```

CREATE REUSABLE FUNCTIONS - THEY SAVE YOU MILLION$

```
protected DataTable GetData(string supportRef)
{
    DAL.TicketsDataSetTableAdapters.TicketDetailsTableAdapter eobj = new DAL.TicketsDataSetTableAdapters.TicketDetailsTableAdapter();
    return eobj.GetTicketUpdates(supportRef);
}
protected void PopulateForm(int i)
{
    ViewState["recordIndex"] = i
    System.Data.DataRow row = dt.Rows[0].Table.Rows[i];
    txtShortDesc.Text = row["ShortDesc"].ToString();
    txtNextStep.Text = row["NextStep"].ToString();
    txtLastUpdated.Text = row["LastUpdated"].ToString();
}
```

PREVIOUS BUTTON

```
  protected void btnPrevious_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      int i = (int)ViewState["recordIndex"];
      i = i <= 0 ? dt.Rows[0].Table.Rows.Count - 1 : i-1;
      PopulateForm(i);
  }
```

NEXT BUTTON

```
protected void btnNext_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      int i = (int)ViewState["recordIndex"];
      i = i >= dt.Rows[0].Table.Rows.Count - 1 ? 0 : i+1;
      PopulateForm(i);
}
```

Here is a JavaScript example that illustrates the algorithm and shows how much more responsive it is when doing this client side instead. It is applicable to C# also

```js
var startWith = 1; // or 0, etc.
var pageNo = startWith;
var recordCount = 5;
var records = [];
for(var i = 0; i < recordCount; i++)
  {
    records.push({TicketRef: "000-00-"+ i, ShortDescription: ['BLUE SCREEN','VIRUS INFECTION','NEW HARDWARE','SOFTWARE UPGRADE','SPILLED SODA ON KEYBOARD','BROKEN CD-ROM'][Math.random()*6|0], NextStep: ['ESCALATE','RESOLVE','RETURN','CLOSE','INVESTIGATE','TRANSFER'][Math.random()*6|0], LastUpdated: ((Math.random()*12|0)+1).toString() + " hours ago" });
    }
renderPageNo = function() {
  $("h1").text(pageNo);
  $("input:text").each(function(){this.value=records[pageNo-startWith][$(this).data("field")];});
}
prev = function() {
  if (pageNo > startWith) pageNo--
    else pageNo = recordCount;
  renderPageNo(pageNo);
}
next = function() {
  if (pageNo < recordCount) pageNo++
    else pageNo = startWith;
  renderPageNo(pageNo);
}
renderPageNo();
$(".btn").eq(0).on("click", prev).end().eq(1).on("click", next);
```

```css
*
{
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  }
label
{
  width: 200px;
  display:block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1></h1>
<label>Ticket Ref<input type='text' data-field="TicketRef"/></label>
<label>Short Description<input type='text' data-field="ShortDescription"/></label>
<label>Next Step<input type='text' data-field="NextStep"/></label>
<label>LastUpdated<input type='text' data-field="LastUpdated"/></label>
<input class='btn' type='button' value='PREV' />
<input class='btn' type='button' value='NEXT' />
```

Comment: Thanks this has got me closer to understanding what i need to do. i am getting an error with the form load, `The name 'i' does not exist in the current context` Also i think the reusable function isnt allowing other areas of the code to see the variable called `dt` so i get another error `The name 'dt' does not exist in the current context`. Should that not be public void?

Comment: Oops - fixed those in answer, too. I didn't have your DAL code so I just psuedocoded it, but now compile errors removed, thanks. And the index is now updated in `ViewState` so that it persists across postbacks.

Comment: This might be useful if you fix the above. The row where you wrote: `System.Data.DataRow row = dt.Rows[0].Table.Rows[i];` well `dt` is returned as empty because you havent passed in data table from `GetData`. You'll find that you get an error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Ignore me i found your error. I will suggest an edit.. :)

Comment: Thanks - I dunno why they didn't approve that edit (I would've), but I fixed it - changed my mind because at one point `LoadData` existed and was void, and forgot to update all code sections when I changed it. Can't compile til I get back in the office tho, hopefully you got your solution running OK. This is a good start, but as a next step, I highly recommend you learn up on AJAX techniques. You users will thank you!

Comment: Yes this is a really good start. Thank you so much for being patient with you! :)... I do find that when the page loads and you click Next, the page looks like its doing something but then on the 2nd click it changes the record.. Strange!

Answer (score 1):

I would provide an index in your database table, which you can then load into the datatable together with the rest of the data. Then you can use that index to go forward and backwards with no hustle by extracting row details based on the index:

```
// store your current row index in a ViewState when first loading the data

ViewState["currentIndex"] = (int)row["RowIndex"];

//When going forward increment your rowIndex to find out the new Row Index
int currentRowIndex = (int) ViewState["currentIndex"];
currentRowIndex++; // ++ to go next -- to go previous

//Get the current row based on rowindex
DataRow row = myDataTable.Select("ID=" + currentRowIndex);
// then use the row data and assign to your textboxes
```

So for example a unique identity key, which is auto incremented by 1 in your database table will help to solve the problem.

Let me break it down a bit further:

Lets assume you fetch your database data on the page Load event:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) {
             // Code to Fetch database data and assign it to a datatable
             // Save DataTable in a ViewState["currentTable"]
             // Get Last Row and assign field values to textboxes
             // Get Last Row index value and assign it to ViewState["currentRowIndex"]

        }
    }
protected void cmdMoveNext_Click(){
          // in this function you going to get your current row index from the ViewState[currentRowIndex]
       int currentIndex = (int)ViewState["currentRowIndex"];
        currentIndex++; // set next row index (currentIndex=currentIndex+1)
         // declare a datatable and assing viewstate["currentTable"] to it
       DataTable myTable = (DataTable)ViewState["currentTable"];

       // Find the DataRow at the new index
       DataRow row = (DataRow) myTable.Select("search by index code");
       // Use the new row values to assign to textboxes
       // Save the new row index in ViewState


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your message. I am getting an error: `The name 'row' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: are you getting it here: ViewState["currentIndex"] = (int)row["RowIndex"];

Comment: 1. Get your data from the database 2. Load it into the datatable 3. Find last row and assing it field values to textboxes 4. Assing the index value to the ViewState

Comment: So you getting the error because variable row has not been declared. You must declare the row variable when you finding the last row in your datatable

Comment: DataRow row = yourTable.Rows[yourTable.Rows.Count-1];

Comment: Thanks that has been very informative!.. I see that you are declaring DataRow row twice.. This is causing me an error with your last line.

Comment: My last line before i sort out my text boxes looks like this: `DataRow row = dt.Select("ID=" + currentRowIndex);`

Comment: I didnt think you will copy and past my code. The above code was just ment to explain how i think your problem can be solved. I would obviously break it down into a few methods and ofcourse you dont need to declare the row variable twice

Comment: It says a local variable is already defined AND `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataRow[]' to 'System.Data.DataRow'`

Comment: Im not just copying and pasting it :) ... I am trying to understand it all... In your last line, you are trying to select the ID from the datatable?

Comment: put (DataRow) dt.Select("blah blah"); which will convert table results to DataRow Type

Comment: ps: are you from Africa?

Comment: i am from Russia, undercover african :)

Comment: My only error is on this line: `DataRow row = (DataRow)dt.Select("ID=" + currentRowIndex);` I already have (datarow) specified.! :(

Comment: I added the following and it worked: `DataRow row = dt.Rows.Add("ID=" + currentRowIndex);`

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same thing but much simpler and without using additional indexers.

Here is what I have done:

```
public OnLoad(...)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        BuidNavigationList();
    }
    LoadNavigation();
}

private List<string> NavigationList
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["NavigationList"] != null)
        {
            return (List<string>)ViewState["NavigationList"];
        }
        return null;
     }
     set
     {
         ViewState["NavigationList"] = value;
     }
}

private void BuidNavigationList()
{
    // ds get

    if (ds.Tables.Count == 1)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = ds.Tables[0];

        if (dataTable.Columns.Contains("YourSwitchColumn"))
        {
            NavigationList = new List<string>(dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => r["YourSwitchColumn"]).Cast<String>());
        }
    }
}

private string YourCurrentSwitchColumnValue
{
    get
    {
        return Request["YourSwitchColumn"].ToString();
    }
}

private void LoadNavigation()
{
     if(this.NavigationList == null)
     {
         lblPrevious.Enabled = false;
         lblNext.Enabled = false;
     }

     int navigationListIndex = NavigationList.IndexOf(YourCurrentSwitchColumnValue);

     if (navigationListIndex == 0)
     {
         lblPrevious.Enabled = false;
         lblNext.Enabled = true;

         lblNext.Value = NavigationList[navigationListIndex + 1];
     }
     else if (navigationListIndex > 0 && navigationListIndex < NavigationList.Count - 1)
     {
         lblPrevious.Enabled = true;
         lblNext.Enabled = true;

         lblPrevious.Value = NavigationList[NavigationListIndex - 1];
         lblNext.Value = NavigationList[NavigationListIndex + 1];                
     }
     else if (navigationListIndex == NavigationList.Count - 1)
     {
         lblPrevious.Enabled = true;
         lblNext.Enabled = false;

         lblPrevious.Value = NavigationList[NavigationListIndex - 1];                
     }
 }

 public void lblNext_OnClick(object sender, ...)
 {
     Request.Redirect("SamePage.aspx?YourSwitchColumn=" + valueFrom_lblNext);
 }
```

*Note this is a demo code you should implement on your needs*